# Did all the Friends kiss each other?

Tags: friends

In the popular TV series [Friends](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108778/?ref_=nv_sr_2) I've seen a lot of kisses between them friends, but is it possible that everyone kissed everybody else?

Comment: If you're including the guys kissing the guys, and the girls kissing the girls, then the answer is likely no.

Comment: @F1Krazy few of them did that too but I am sure not all

Comment: Seriously, what is the **value** in this question?

Comment: If you're talking relationships, then according to this website, the answer is no.   http://friends.wikia.com/wiki/Relationships but hello/goodbye/friendship kisses - I have no idea.

Comment: @Paulie_D As it is, maybe there is none (though the OP could probably elaborate). But I'm guessing I (sadly) can still answer this if I think about it long enough, if anyone's interested. ;) I know Rachel and Phoebe kissed everyone (Edit: Chandler too, actually).

Comment: At *best* this is trivia but it's hardly relevant unless the OP has a **specific** point to make.

Comment: Yeah. OP can just find the answer [here](https://www.quora.com/Did-Chandler-and-Ross-Monica-and-Joey-ever-kiss), then, just came across it. It's elaborate enough.

Comment: @Paulie_D - Well, it *could* be useful if you live in a culture where casual kissing is not done, and you are curious what the limits on this behavior are in the Friends-verse.

Comment: @Paulie_D Does every question need to have a particular point to it?

Comment: @MaxAstall On SE, yeah, I'm afraid they do...

Comment: @MaxAstall Yes, trivia is specifically off-topic and the point here is that questions, *ideally* should add to the overall enjoyment and **understanding** of the movie/show...and this *does not seem to qualify* UNLESS the OP has a wider point to make..and that hasn't happened yet.

Answer (score 5):

Qualified yes.

If you combine [this chart](https://www.reddit.com/r/howyoudoin/comments/49oaff/did_everyone_kiss_each_other/) and the [IMDB trivia page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108778/trivia) that shows Monica and Phoebe did kiss, then every main character has kissed every other main character.

However, as Walt points out, the Chandler/Ross smooch never occurs on screen, and is only hinted at, so that is the most questionable of the grouping.

Comment: I disagree. The Joey-Monica kiss wasn't real, it happened in a fantasy. But even if *that* one counts, the Chandler-Ross kiss is never seen and only *vaguely* hinted at, he might not have kissed him at all.

Comment: @Walt - Sounds like a competing answer, and the specification is not for "on screen", but "did they".

Comment: Well, this is pretty much trivia, so I probably won't answer. But again, there's no *hard* evidence for a Chandler-Ross kiss, really.

Comment: @Walt - I updated to include that point.

Comment: Ross didn't kiss Monica though.. not like OP meant